# Probability of iterated coin flips with “cutoff” threshold

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Suppose Alice and Bob play a game of chance: they repeatedly flip a coin, and if it comes up heads, Alice gets a point, otherwise Bob gets a point. Once one player’s score reaches some fixed threshold, that player wins the game.

After a few coin tosses, Alice still needs $n$ more points to win, while Bob still needs $m$. The two wonder what the probability $P(A)$ is that Alice will win. Naturally, if $n = 0$, Alice has won, while if $m = 0$, Bob has won. In all other cases, there are two equally probable futures: one in which Alice scores the next point and one in which Bob does. This yields the following recurrence relation for $P(A)$:

$$ P_{n,m}(A) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n = 0$ and $m > 0$,} \\
0 & \text{if $n > 0$ and $m = 0$,} \\
\frac{1}{2} P_{n-1,m}(A) + \frac{1}{2} P_{n,m-1}(A) & \text{if $n > 0$ and $m > 0$.}
\end{cases} $$

But is there some closed-form solution? It simplifies things slightly to factor out $1/2^{n+m-1}$ to obtain an integer-valued function:

$$ \begin{gathered}
P_{n,m}(A) = \frac{f(n,m)}{2^{n+m-1}} \\[6pt]
%
f(n,m) = \begin{cases}
2^{m-1} & \text{if $n = 0$ and $m > 0$,} \\
0 & \text{if $n > 0$ and $m = 0$,} \\
f(n-1,m) + f(n,m-1) & \text{if $n > 0$ and $m > 0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{gathered} $$

Notably, this definition of $f$ is equivalent to a sum of binomial coefficients:

$$ f(n,m) = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{i} $$

However, I’m not sure if there’s a simpler solution. If I fix one of $n$ or $m$ to some small value, finding one-dimensional solutions is not too hard:

$$ \begin{align*}
f(n,1) &= 1 \\[2pt]
%
f(n,2) &= f(0,2) + \sum_{i=1}^n f(i,1) \\
       &= n + 2 \\[8pt]
%
f(n,3) &= f(0,3) + \sum_{i=1}^n f(i,2) \\
       &= 4 + \sum_{i=1}^n (i+2) \\[1pt]
       &= \frac{n(n+5)}{2}+4 \\[8pt]
%
f(n,4) &= f(0,4) + \sum_{i=1}^n f(i,3) \\
       &= 8 + \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{i(i+5)}{2} + 4 \right) \\[1pt]
       &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12} + \frac{5n(n+1)}{4} + 4n + 8 \\[2pt]
       &= \frac{n(n+4)(n+5)}{6} + 2n + 8
\end{align*} $$

Unfortunately, this process wasn’t enough for me to understand how to generalize my solutions to arbitrary $n$ and $m$. Is there some nice way to do it?

Comment: The probabilities can be expressed nicely using a binomial distribution CDF (imagine what might happen in the next $n+m-1$ points even if not all of them need be played), so either as a sum of binomial probabilities which for given $m$ gives a polynomial in $n$ as you have found, or using a regularized incomplete beta function.  There is not a simple closed form for general $n$ and $m$

Comment: The gambler's ruin theory gives formulas for the chance that the player will win.

Comment: @Henry Indeed, I realized $f(n,m)$ is just $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{i}$ shortly after posting this question (for better or for worse), which I think probably mostly answers it. But I’ll leave it open in case someone can supply a nice explanation for why no closed form exists.

Comment: It is worth noting that this question was the subject of correspondence in 1654 between Fermat and Pascal, one of the foundations of probability theory. They were considering the fair division of the stake in an interrupted game of chance, known as the [problem of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points). Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3040128/probability-of-winning-coin-tosses-variable-number-of-games